# Large Query or mutate Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using a SparkSession to connect to a hive database. I'm trying to decide what is the best way to enrichment the data. I was using Spark Sql but I am weary to use it.

1. Does the SparkSql just call Hive Sql? So would that mean there is no improved performance from using Spark?
2. If not, should I just create a large sql query to spark, or should I grab a table I wan't convert it to a data frame and manipulate it using sparks functions?

Comment: It's either this or that. Improving performance with spark is related to so many issues, i.e data locality, sparsity, whether you have enough RAM to load it or not... Thus we can't give a concrete answer for your question. And like mentioned by @RickMoritz, well you have to test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, Spark will read the data from Hive, but use its own execution engine. Performance and capabilities will differ. How much depends on the execution engine you are using for Hive. (M/R, Tez, Spark, LLAP?)
2. That's the same thing. I would stick to SQL queries, and A-B-test against Hive in the beginning, but SQL is notoriously difficult to maintain, where Scala/Python code using Spark's DataSet API is more user friendly in the long term.